# While truncating a text file in python , I am getting "File not open for truncating" even though I open that file. Details down there

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error

```
from sys import argv
script , filename = argv

print(f"\n\nThis program is meant to truncate {filename}")

print("Opening The file ...")
target = open(filename)

print("\n\n Truncating the file ...")
target.truncate()

print(f"Now, I will ask you for 1 line to put into {filename}")

line1 = input("line 1 :")
line2 = input("line 2 :")

target.write(line1)
target.write('\n')
target.write(line2)

print("Closing the file ...")
target.close()
```

---

That was the code and this is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex9.py", line 10, in <module>
    target.truncate()
io.UnsupportedOperation: File not open for writing
```

---

The code is in python
Why is this happening? I am opening the file
  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file in write mode.

`open(filename)` will not do the trick because this only opens it in it's default state (`r`)

you need to add the parameter 'w' to it to write to the file:

from [The BSD fopen manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fopen/)

> ``w''   Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing.
>            The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

You should try this to make your case work:

```
target = open(filename, 'w')
```

Use `w+` if you also want to read it, but I guess this is not needed in your case.

Comment: what is the difference between 'fopen' and 'open' ?? Is 'open' wrong ??

Comment: `open` is a build-in function by python, it differs from `os.open`. I search for some arguments why to use `fopen` but couldn't really find any, so I removed it from my answer :)